# Specifying gitea server Gitea Base URL when it is normally accessed via SSH Local Port Forwarding?

Tags: git, reverse-proxy, gitea

On my gitea server, I normally access it via ssh Local Port Forwarding; and it isn't accessible from the outside because I bind it to the localhost address.

I'm accessing it from `http://127.0.0.1:8080` via "Local Port Forwarding", and it thinks that it's being accessed from `http://127.0.0.1:3000`; so certain features (the preview in the wiki and the issues for instance do not work (you can however save them, just not preview them); anyway it's mis-configured, see below, I'd like to change the `Gitea Base URL` so that anytime the server currently writes `http://127.0.0.1:3000` it will write `http://127.0.0.1:8080` instead (but that said, it would be good if it still operated off of port `3000`):

[image: gitea configuration]

What line in `gitea.ini` changes this functionality? or is it more like a situation where I need to throw a reverse proxy in front of it that rewrites the URLs for me?

Answer (score 2):

I did not struggle with port numbers but meant to change the domain (localhost to foo) and found `ROOT_URL` mentioned in the [config cheat sheet](https://docs.gitea.io/en-us/config-cheat-sheet/#server-server):

> ROOT_URL: %(PROTOCOL)s://%(DOMAIN)s:%(HTTP_PORT)s/: Overwrite the
> automatically generated public URL. This is useful if the internal and
> the external URL don’t match (e.g. in Docker).

There is also a HTTP_PORT option which could apply to you as well.

See your `/path/to/gitea/conf/app.ini` -> `[server]` section and change accordingly

```
[server]
  APP_DATA_PATH    = /path/to/gitea
  DOMAIN           = localhost
  SSH_DOMAIN       = localhost
  HTTP_PORT        = 3000
  ROOT_URL         = http://localhost:3000/
```

> I'd like to change the Gitea Base URL so that anytime the server
> currently writes http://127.0.0.1:3000 it will write
> http://127.0.0.1:8080 instead (but that said, it would be good if it
> still operated off of port 3000):

I assume setting ROOT_URL to `http://127.0.0.1:8080` but leaving HTTP_PORT to default `3000` should do that.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I changed the ROOT_URL but the web doesn't show anymore. Should I log in as "git" account? or is there anything to modify "app.ini" file?

Comment: @CloudCho changing the ROOT_URL should only affect links _automatically generated by gitea_. If you could connect to your installation via gitea.example.com it should still be the same - regardless the value of ROOT_URL

Comment: thanks for the information. "installation via gitea.example.com"...would you share web link? I couldn't find in Google.

Comment: Sorry, I meant whatever URL you use to access your installation. Only you will know. I used a generic example. See https://example.com/

Comment: thanks for extra explanation. By the way please, check the link...it looks like incorrect one.